# How to exclude an item based on template when using find-item in Powershell

Tags: content-search, powershell-extensions

I'm working on this script:

```
$criteria = @(
    @{Filter = "NotEquals"; Field = "_template"; Value = "{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}"}  
)
$props = @{
    Index = "sitecore_master_index"
    Criteria = $criteria

}
Find-Item @props
```

However I kept on getting this error:

> Find-Item : Cannot bind parameter 'Criteria'. Cannot create object of type "Spe.Commands.Data.Search.SearchCriteria". Cannot convert value "NotEquals" to type "Spe.Commands.Data.Search.FilterType". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name NotEqual to a valid enumerator name.

I tried keywords for Filter such as: `"Equals"`, `"Equal"`, `"NotContains"` but still I kept getting the same error. Anynone could help me what's causing the issue? Basically I just want to exclude a certain items based on its `templateid`.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

There is no `NotEquals` support for `Filter`.

But any condition can be negated if you use `Invert = $true`

```
$criteria = @(
    @{
        Filter = "Equals"; 
        Field = "_template"; 
        Value = "{A87A00B1-E6DB-45AB-8B54-636FEC3B5523}";
        Invert = $true;
    }  
)
```

I don't remember, maybe you need to lowercase and remove special chars from template ID: `a87a00b1e6db45ab8b54636fec3b5523`

There is more documentation about `Find-Item` here: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/appendix/indexing/find-item

Comment: Thanks, this one works!